# Azure log analytics query for how much and what data has vm consumed

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

I would like to have query that would return something like for single vm. So query should be showing results of single vm and what kinda log type / solutions it has used and how much.
[image]
I don't know if this is even possible to do anything similar maybe? Tips?

With this query I'm able to list total usage for all vm's reporting to laws but I would like to have more details about a single vm

```
find where TimeGenerated > ago(30d) project _BilledSize, _IsBillable, Computer
| where _IsBillable == true 
| extend computerName = tolower(tostring(split(Computer, '.')[0]))
| summarize BillableDataBytes = sum(_BilledSize) by  computerName 
| sort by BillableDataBytes nulls last
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly you would be able to accomplish it by querying standard columns or properties **_BilledSize**, **Type**, **_IsBillable** and **Computer**.

**Below is the sample query for your reference:**

```
union withsource=tt *
| where TimeGenerated between (ago(7d) .. now())
| where _IsBillable == true
| where isnotempty(Computer) 
| where Computer == "MM-VM-RHEL-7"
| summarize BillableDataBytes = sum(_BilledSize) by Computer, _IsBillable, Type
| render piechart
```

**Below is the screenshot for illustration:**

[image]

**Related references:**

- [Log data usage - Understanding ingested data volume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/manage-cost-storage#understanding-ingested-data-volume)
- [Standard columns in logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/log-standard-columns)